# Add-AzVMDataDisk not attaching disk

Tags: powershell, azure

I am attempting to attach an unmanaged blob, which is a copy of a snapshot of the os disk, to an existing VM as a data disk. The VM doesn't currently have any data disks.

```
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroup "mygroup" -Name "myvm"
$disk = $vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk
$blob = ... bunch of code that creates a snapshot and copies to a blob ...
$diskName = "my-data-disk"
$blobUri = $blob.ICloudBlob.Uri.ToString()

$res = Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name $diskName -CreateOption 'Attach' -VhdUri $destBlobUri -DiskSizeInGB $disk.DiskSizeGB -Lun 0 -Caching 'ReadOnly'
$attached = $res.SotrageProfile.DataDisks
```

`$attached` shows as the disk just attached, but it doesn't appear in the portal under VM -> disks -> Data Disks.

Is the fact that I am attempting to attach a snapshot of the OS disk to the same VM an issue?

I am doing that only for convenience while testing at this point, eventually the VM it is attached to will be a backup VM.

The full script for reference:

```
Import-Module './lib/RedSky.psm1' -Force

# Load backup config (todo: alow pass config on command line)
# Note, this will make sure we are logged in aswell
$config = Get-RsConfig './backup-config.json'

# Check we can find the VM, bail if not
$vm = Get-RsVM $config.ResourceGroup $config.VirtualMachine
$vm
if (!$vm) {
  write-host "VM not in list of VMs"
  exit 1
}

write-host "Selected VM: $($vm.name) in $($vm.ResourceGroupName), $($vm.Location)"

$destContainer = "vhd-backups"
$destBlobSuffix = "duplicacy-" + (get-date).ToString(‘yyyyMMdd_HHmmss’)

foreach ($backup in $config.Backups) {
  write-host " Source Disk: $($backup.Source.Disk)"
  $disk = Get-RsVMDisk $vm $backup.Source.Disk
  if ($disk -And $disk.Vhd) {
    # Work out storage account, container and blob names from disk URI
    $uri = $disk.Vhd.Uri
    $storageAccount = $uri.split('/')[2].split('.')[0]  # e.g. rg1disks
    $containerName = $uri.split('/')[3]                 # e.g. vhds
    $blobName = $uri.split('/')[-1]                     # e.g. rsa-oz1YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.vhd
    $destBlob = $blobName.split(".vhd")[0] + "-" + $destBlobSuffix + ".vhd"
    $destName = $desbBlobSuffix

    # Log what we are dealing with (change to -verbose at some point)
    write-host "  DiskUri: $uri"
    write-host "  Disk Size: $($disk.DiskSizeGB)"
    write-host "  Resource Group: $($vm.ResourceGroupName)"
    write-host "  Location: $($vm.Location)"
    write-host "  Storage Account: $storageAccount"
    write-host "  Container Name: $containerName"
    write-host "  DiskBlob Name: $blobName"
    write-host "  Dest Container: $descContainer"
    write-host "  Disk Name: $destName"
    write-host "  Dest Blob: $destBlob"

    # Snapshot the disk, copy it, then remove the snapshot
    $storageContext = Get-RsStorageContext $vm.ResourceGroupName $storageAccount
    $snapshot = New-RsSnapshot $storageContext $containerName $blobName
    $blob = Copy-RsSnapshotToBlob $storageContext $snapshot $destContainer $destBlob
    Remove-RsSnapshot $snapshot

    $destBlobUri = $blob.ICloudBlob.Uri.ToString()
    write-host "  Dest Blob URI: $destBlobUri"

    # Attach blob to VM
    $res = Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name $destBlob -CreateOption 'Attach' -VhdUri $destBlobUri -DiskSizeInGB $disk.DiskSizeGB -Lun 1 -Caching 'ReadOnly'
    if ($res -eq $vm) {
      foreach ($attached in $vm.StorageProfile.DataDisks) {
        if ($attached.Name -eq $destBlob) {
          write-host "  Attached Disk: $($attached.Name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to also call `Update-AzVM` to commit the changes.